# Unable to install .apk from /system/priv-app

Tags: adb, installation, apk, system-apps

I moved my apk file to `/system/priv-app` just as you adviced me in [this thread.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180347/installing-apk-as-system-app-directly-with-root) When I'm trying to install it through clicking this .apk, Android said me that "The application has not been installed". I tried to use `adb install myapp.apk` for this purpose but again ADB  gave me an error: `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION]` and I suppose that app requires permission which can be granted only by root. So the only way I see now is to run `adb shell` later `su` next `cd /system/priv-app` and `install [-cdDsp] [-o USER] [-g GRP] [-m MODE] [-t DIR] [SOURCE]... DEST` and that's a point because I totally don't understand this legend:

```
    Copy files and set attributes
    -c      Just copy (default)
    -d      Create directories
    -D      Create leading target directories
    -s      Strip symbol table
    -p      Preserve date
    -o USER Set ownership
    -g GRP  Set group ownership
    -m MODE Set permissions
    -t DIR  Install to DIR`
```

How to set attributes to install this apk as system app?

Comment: Because this `install` is **not a command for Android**. It's for Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the whole process. You are not supposed to use install command or the likes of it anywhere in the process [I mentioned](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180358/96277). You simply:

1. [mount the system partition in rw mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110928/96277)
2. copy-paste the apk into the location,
3. set the appropriate permissions using busybox's chmod and chgrp or through inbuilt tools:

   ```
   adb shell su -c chmod 644 APK    # replace APK with your apk's absolute location, such as /system/priv-app/xyz.apk
   adb shell su -c chown root:root APK   # replace APK as said above
   ```
4. do a reboot.

Follow those instructions religiously. You can altogether avoid the commands using a file manager app such as Solid File Explorer, ES File Explorer, etc.

During the following boot the Android would detect the apk and install it automatically.

Comment: Can a fact that this APK haven't got a signature be the obstacle to this automatical installation?

Comment: Yes. An APK without a valid signature can't be installed normally.

Comment: Ok. I understand.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Firelord, you can eliminate the hussle of entering commands (and possibly reduce the likelihood of errors) using a file explorer such as the one mentioned already.

For instance with ES explorer, simply long press the target `.apk` file and choose properties then edit:

[image]

Afterwards you get proper permissions i.e `-rw- r-- r--` and owner i.e `root`:

[image]

*Disclaimer: the app used above in example is my own-made app, so you won't find it in playstore*

Answer (score 1):

You should move the APK file to `/system/priv-app`, then change its file mode to 0664 (-rw-r--r--) and change its owner to root:root.

```
chmod 0644 your.apk
chown 0.0 your.apk
```

Then it should be fine.