# How to prevent uninstalling applications

Tags: application-manager

How can I prevent uninstalling selected applications by mistake? can I add a user application to device administrator for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot add any app as a device administrator unless it has provisions for it. What you can do is convert those apps as system apps. The process **requires root access**. Follow:

- [How do I properly install a system app given its .apk?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/27/96277)
- [Installing .apk as system app directly (with root)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/180347/96277)

You can alternatively, albeit with root access, disable the component `com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity`. ([Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir) can do that easily.) That component shows the the dialog to uninstall the app. If you prevent the appearance of that you won't be able to uninstall the app *through GUI*.

**In absence of root access**, consider disabling the Package Installer app. It is a system app which handles installation (sideloaded apps) and uninstallation of apps through GUI. It can be disabled from Settings → Apps → (three-dots line → Show System) or (All Apps) → Package Installer → Disable.

One **side effect** of disabling Package Installer completely or its aforesaid component is that you won't be able to uninstall any app through Settings app either (Play Store is exception). Re-enable Package Installer to uninstall any app from Settings app again.