# How to make an app that users can't uninstall for a set period of time?

Tags: uninstallation, application-manager

Related to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/183045/how-to-prevent-uninstalling-applications).

I want to make an app that users can download from the Play Store, set a time range in different ways, and cannot uninstall the app during that time period. Once the time period is over, they should be able to uninstall the app.

Is this possible without the user having root access?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while this community might explain the technicality of Android OS to your queries, coding solutions are out of the scope of this community. For programming questions, you might want to try our sister site [so].